# extra factor variable in stargazer output

Tags: r, stargazer

I am using stargazer to summarize multiple models for my regression analyses, see coding below. The last variable is CAD, which is a factor variable with 2 levels (0 and 1). In the output, it keeps printing an estimate for not only CAD but also CAD1. This is not happening for any of the other factor variables.

Any ideas why there is this duplicative estimation?

If I take away CAD, so that "diabetes" is the last variable estimated, it also adds another entry for diabetes to be diabetes1..

Code:

```
stargazer(model.objects.data[[1]], model.objects.data[[2]], model.objects.data[[3]], model.objects.data[[4]], 
          ci = TRUE, ci.level = 0.95, 
          single.row = TRUE, 
          digits = 2, 
          covariate.labels = c("predictor", "Age (years)", "Current Smoking", "Education (years)", "APOE4+", "Male", "BMI (kg/m2)", "Hypertension", "Diabetes", "CAD"),
          star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001), 
          dep.var.caption = "",
          type = "text", output = "mydata.txt")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have an intercept in your estimated coefficients that you are not providing a covariate.label for?

Comment: Hi Dan: In the output, the intercept is labeled automatically w/ "Constant" for all of my models. I do not seem to need to specify that.